Dependant radio buttons in Microsoft Word
I created a form in a MS Words document including a set of radio buttons (Option Buttons) to select from (What team should the request go to: Team 1, Team 2 or Team 3). These should always stay the same.
Depending on what Team the user selects, this should update or make appear a second set of radio buttons in the subsequent question ("What type of request?"). So, when clicking on Team 1, the Radio button selection in this section should become Request 1a, Request 1b. For Team 2, the selection should become Request 2a, Request 2b. For Team 3 the selection becomes Request 3a, Request 3b.
How can I code this in VBA?
Edit: the "Request" names for the selection are just an example, I would like to be able to rename them individually.


Assuming the name of team option buttons are OptionButton1 OptionButton2 OptionButton3, and they are InlineShape.

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    UpdateOptBtn 1
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    UpdateOptBtn 2
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    UpdateOptBtn 3
End Sub

Sub UpdateOptBtn(ByVal iD As Long)
    Dim s As InlineShape
    Dim sCap As String
    Const GRP_NAME = "request"
    For Each s In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        With s.OLEFormat.Object
            If .GroupName = GRP_NAME Then
                 sCap = .Caption
                 .Caption = Left(sCap, Len(sCap) - 2) & iD & Right(sCap, 1)
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub



Update:
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    UpdateOptBtn "general requests|approval requests"
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    UpdateOptBtn "modify requests|data requests"
End Sub

Sub UpdateOptBtn(ByVal sCap As String)
    Dim s As InlineShape, i As Long
    Dim aName, aCaption
    Const OPT_BTNS = "OptionButton4|OptionButton5"
    aName = Split(OPT_BTNS, "|")
    aCaption = Split(sCap, "|")
    If UBound(aName) = UBound(aCaption) Then
        For i = LBound(aName) To UBound(aName)
            On Error Resume Next
            For Each s In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
                If s.OLEFormat.Object.Name = aName(i) Then
                    s.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = aCaption(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub



This is great. Would it be possible to modify the code so that I can I rename the request buttons. They have longer names. request 1, 2 etc this was just an example. They should also be vertically aligned.

Pls provide the name of opt-btn in your file. As long as it has a pattern, it can be done by code. They should also be vertically aligned. - The location/alignment of opt-btns are not a matter.

The  names for the captions would be for example "general requests", "approval request ", "data requests", the only pattern here would be that it ends with request.I was thinking maybe it's possible to use case statement here
